# Exiting application in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have used SystemNavigator.pop(); to exit the application programmatically in flutter after I exit the app it stays in background when I reopen it in some phone(Android) the app restart but in some it just continues from the exit screen until I manually termite it from the background why so????

I am trying to figure out the proper App exiting method in flutter, The App exit method systemNavigaor.pop() behaves differently for different phone (Android)

Comment: Try `exit(1)` but I'm not sure if it's the right one.

Comment: You shouldn't ever programatically terminate an app on iOS.  Why would you want to do this?  It isn't what the user expects.

Comment: yes, but in android systemnavigator.pop() behaves differently for different phones why so??